# Find the sum of all the even-valued terms in the sequence which do not exceed four million

Tags: c, fibonacci

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
I made the program but my answer doesnt match.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 long unsigned int i,sum=0,x=1,y=2,num;
 for(i=0;i<4000000;i++)
 {
  num=x+y;
  if(i%2==0)
   sum+=num;
  x=y;
  y=num;
 }
 printf("%lu\n",sum);
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it asking for all of the numbers in the sequence whose INDEX is even, or all numbers in the sequence that ARE even?

Comment: "Even-valued", not "at even positions".

Comment: @TaslemGuy you should write that as an answer

Comment: If you're just going down the [list of problems](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three problems I can see:

- You should start with `x = 1, y = 1`, since otherwise you skip the first even-valued Fibonacci;
- Your loop condition should be `(x + y) <= 4000000`
- You should test `num` for even-ness, not `i`.

(After these changes, it should be obvious that you can omit `i` entirely, and therefore replace the `for` loop with a `while` loop)

Comment: why (x+y)<=4000000 and not num<=4000000?

Comment: @fahad: Because the test is run *before* the loop executed, so it happens before `num` is calculated.  And if you start with `x=1,y=1` then the first number tested is 3, not 2.

Comment: I guess it shoulnt be x+y there but just y.seehttp://forum.projecteuler.net/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=1458

Comment: @fahad: There lots of ways to go about it, but I was going for the minimal changes to your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you find the sum of fibonacci numbers with even index, not even numbers themselves + you search the first 4000000 numbers in sequence, not the numbers with values <= 4000000. Your code should be something like

```
while ( y < 4000000){
...
if (y %2 == 0)
    sum += y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a minimal set of corrections and now get the right answer. You may learn more by reading this (after all, it was yours, to start with) than by me rambling on about it...

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIMIT (4 * 1000 * 1000)

int main() {
  long unsigned int sum = 0, x = 1, y = 2, num;

  while (x <= LIMIT) {
    if ((x & 1) == 0 && x <= LIMIT)
      sum += x;
    num = x + y;
    x = y;
    y = num;
  }
  printf("%lu\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the following line

```
if(i%2==0)
```

might instead be

```
if( num % 2 == 0)
```

On further thinking, I think you don't actually need the variable `i`. Instead, your loop can be controlled by num as:

```
enum { LIMIT = 4 * 1000 * 1000 };
num = x + y;
while( num <= LIMIT ) {
```

Comment: Hmm.. Any reason for down vote? If the answer is incorrect, please comment, so that I can learn my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

print num inside the loop, for debugging

```
 for(i=0;i<4000000;i++)
 {
  num=x+y;
  printf("num is %lu\n", num); /* DEBUGGING */
  if(i%2==0)
   sum+=num;
  x=y;
  y=num;
 }
```