# Debug C program to sum up all even terms of the Fibonacci Sequence under 4 Million

Tags: c, loops, fibonacci

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long int first=1,second=2,sum=0,a[4000000],i=0;
    while(second<4000000)
    {
        a[i]=first;
        second=first+second;
        first=second-first;
        i++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<1999999;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+ a[2*i+1];
    }
    printf("The required sum is : %d",sum);
}
```

I am not able to detect the error, it is running an infinite loop I guess
No Compile time errors found but no result obtained

Comment: I doubt Windows is very happy with your 15.25 MB of stack usage. I'm surprised this doesn't crash.  Why wouldn't you start out using smaller numbers to verify things are working?

Comment: Fibonacci[33] is about 3.5 millions, so you need to sum only half of 33 values. Why do you sum values from 0th to 1999999th? Why don't you initialize array with zeroes?

Comment: @user3656952 Are you sure the program runs an infinite loop.  The error Jonathon Reinhart pointed out would cause it to crash on startup.  This would also cause your reported problem of "no result obtained".

Comment: Seems to be [Problem 2](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=2) from Project Euler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the sum of all the even-valued terms in the sequence which do not exceed four million](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847992/find-the-sum-of-all-the-even-valued-terms-in-the-sequence-which-do-not-exceed-fo)

Comment: According to your code, you should change the title from "even terms" to "terms on even indices". This raises a question as to what you meant by "4000000" - did you mean term #4000000 or the largest term with a value smaller than 4000000? In addition, please note that the Fibonacci sequence starts as `0,1,1,2,3` and not as `1,2,3`. So you are essentially missing a `1` in the final outcome.

Comment: hint: integer overflow.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to store all the numbers under 4 million - just calculate the numbers on the fly in your first and second variables, and add every other one into your sum.

Answer (score 2):

Based on mc110's answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const int LIMIT = 4000000;
    long int first=0,second=1;
    long int sum=0;
    while(second<LIMIT)
    {
        if( (second % 2) == 0)  // we only want even numbers
          sum += second;

        // could be optimized even more by simply swapping first/second
        long int tmp = first;  
        first = second;
        second += tmp;
    }
    printf("The required sum is : %d",sum);
}
```

gives me (spoiler alert)

> The required sum is : 4613732

Comment: According to the title of the question, OP indeed wants to sum up even numbers. But according to the code within the question itself, OP in fact wants to sum up numbers on even indices.

Comment: @barakmanos: Yeah. I summed up all numbers first, but then recognized the question being a duplicate, then recognized the *real* question. The OPs code is wrong regarding many points, so this is just one more. My guess would be that (at least:-) the caption is right.

Comment: @barakmanos http://projecteuler.net/problem=2